# Create entire UIView within UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController (controller1) which is displaying some UIbuttons on a UIView.  When one of the buttons is clicked I'd like to instantiate a second UIViewController (controller2, which is of an entirely different controller class) which will then create some UIViews programmatically and add these to one of the UIViews being managed by controller1.

So, in controller1 I'd like the following code:

```
- (void) someButtonPressed: (id)sender
{
    ViewController2* controller2 = [ [ ViewController2 alloc ] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil ];
}
```

I'd then like to programmatically create the additional UIViews within controller2.  Ideally I will not have any further lines of code within controller1 (to add views and suchlike).  I'd really like to create all views and add them to the existing views from within the controller2 code.

Can I do this, and how?  I've tried simply placing the following code in controller2:

```
- (void)loadView
{

    NSLog(@"HPSViewEditorViewController loadView");

}
```

but it does not get called.

I want to encapsulate the entire UIView hierarchy for controller2 in the controller2 code, and don't want to 'clutter up' controller1 with anything other than the controller2 instantiation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like

```
[viewController1 presentModalViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
```

This could do the trick...

Comment: Great, works a treat.  No need for loadView either.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Anselm - slight problem; when displaying the view for the second controller the entire screen goes black.  I want the contents of the previous views to 'show through' the view belonging to controller2.  Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: I am not 100 % sure but I would try to give the background the UIColor clearcolor... :-)

Answer (score 0):

From [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The view controller calls this method when its view property is requested but is currently nil. This method loads or creates a view and assigns it to the view property.

-loadView will not be called until controller2.view is referenced.

Comment: So, is there any way to reference it from within controller2?